# Windows Azure Storage Emulator failed to install

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I almost wasted my whole day trying to install Windows Azure Storage Emulator but somehow it is not getting installed..

The log is showing me this error : Sql instance not found. I tried re-installing Sql server 2012 but it did not help. It is not able to find Sql instance at all..

Here is the detailed log : http://pastebin.com/KUW4mjuf

I tried googling around but ended up with no solution at all.

:-( I can't go ahead without Azure Storage emulator..

I hope somebody here will help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There may be an issue with the sqllocaldb user database v11.0 during the install.
You need to recreate it (see below).

As far as I'm concerned, my first install attemp left some files in my c:\users[user] directory :

- WAStorageEmulatorDb30.mdf
- WAStorageEmulatorDb30_log.ldf

(Your version numbers may differ.)  The sqllocaldb logs would mention these files still existed and it would not erase them.

I just deleted them manually. 
Recreated the v11.0:

- sqllocaldb stop v11.0
- sqllocaldb delete v11.0
- sqllocaldb create v11.0

And reinstalled.

Comment: Worked for me, as backed by https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2644640f-f473-4d63-aa6a-4077714d0461/caquietexec-error-cannot-create-database?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: This is a workaround. For me the actual cause of the problem was the sysadmin of the SQL LocalDb was no good. Added myself as the sysadmin of the SQL LocalDb fixed the installation problem. Tested with Azure SDK 2.3 and 2.4.

Comment: The answer could be more clear, I missed the part about deleting the emulator files which was crucial for this to work. This answer pointed that out to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23364274/134761

Comment: This worked for me. First delete the two WAStorageEmulatorDb* files (my version differed). Then, at an elevated cmd prompt, run the sqllocaldb commands in that order, except I omitted the version argument completely as I have 12 installed but neither v11.0 nor v12.0 succeeded. Then, re-ran WPI, installed Azure SDK 2.8.1, and this time the storage emulator installed where before it errored consistently. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for storage emulator 4.3 as well, in my case, no need to recreate the MSSQLLocalDB, installer will create it for you, only need to delete the older instance before running installer

Comment: Just had the same problem with recently released Storage Emulator 4.6 and this fixed it. Seems to be a common problem with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For those who has new **Azure Storage Emulator 4.5** and **SQL Server 2016**. As [MWood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278889/mwood) mentioned, check `c:\users[UserProfile]` directory and delete any **AzureStorage*** databases found.

Then **open command window** and write same commands, but change database to **V13** (*the number depends on the SQL server database version installed on your machine)*.

```
sqllocaldb stop v13.0
sqllocaldb delete v13.0
sqllocaldb create v13.0
```

[image]

Then install [Azure SDK tools](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) again.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too. But I solved it with it:

- Programs and Features
- Selected Visual Studio 2015
- Selected "Change -> Modify"
- Checked "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tool" and Click "Install"

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had just uninstalled SQL Server 2016 RC and installed the production version, must've removed something I shouldn't have!

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me.  I'm using Parallels on OSX and have an automatic "network profile" with a long path name for my desktop and download folders.  Parallels does this automatically

Another solution that worked for me:

- Manually download the MSI referenced in the error log
- Create a new LOCAL username (not passport/LiveID connected)
- Install the MSI from C:\  NOT downloads (where Parallels is backing it as a UNC)

I think it's hitting a 255 char limitation in Windows UNCs'

Answer (score 0):

To keep my laptop responsive during startup, I have changed the sqlserver (express) service startup to manual during its installation. Emulator failed without any error that sql server is not running. On seeing this question, I realized to start the sql server service and then, the installation (emulator 3.2) wen through.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem for myself by running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" create MSSQLLocalDB
```

Simple but effective.