# Azure Storage Emulator fails to install

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage, localdb, failed-installation

I'm at wits end. I've had a go at this for 2 days, but to no avail. Sigh...

Installing the Azure Storage Emulator 3.3 fails. I've tried using Platform Installer and standalone installer. Earlier versions fail as well. Event Viewer yields an unhandled exception from WAStorageEmulator.exe 3 times before giving up:

```
Application: WAStorageEmulator.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code e0434352, exception address 00007FFFEC8A5BF8
Stack:
```

The logfile might indicate that it happens here:

```
WAStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
```

Here's a logfile from the installation: http://bit.ly/1oJGlyv. (verbose version here: http://bit.ly/ZoVheR). It says error code 1603, which is very generic. I also see a bunch of question marks, where others have had more helpful messages.

I've followed every advice I could find, including deleting localdb files and restarting it (e.g. here: [Windows Azure Storage Emulator failed to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885318/windows-azure-storage-emulator-failed-to-install)).

Running Windows 8.1, SQL Express installed.

**Sidenote:** Tried to run Microsoft's Fix It tool, but that fails to start with an unhandled exception like the one above. My system runs smoothly like butter, and I would very much like avoid having to re-install everything.

Answer (score 0):

No cure. Ended up re-installing Windows from scratch. Should have done that immediately... Thanks M$.