# Failed to initialize Microsoft Azure storage emulator SDK2.8

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

[image]I am unable to start Azure Emulator.

Getting Error as:

```
Microsoft Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Microsoft Azure storage emulator. 
The storage emulator needs to be initialized. Please run the 'init' command. Cannot create database.
```

Tried replacing AzureStorageEmulator.exe port names but seems its not working.
Also tried to run Azure prompt in admin mode and tried to write DSInit /sqlInstance: But its showing error as DSInit not internal command.

Any help on this please.

Comment: Storage Emulator uses localdb. so you need check it first. Do you have any localdb instances in `SQL Server Object Explorer` window in Visual Studio?

Comment: What happens when you do `AzureStorageEmulator init`?

Comment: @GauravMantri I directly typed AzureStorageEmulator.exe init, but still no change in error

Comment: @llya Chumakov Added image of DB in VS..,

Comment: Please see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885318/windows-azure-storage-emulator-failed-to-install.

Comment: @ShopShop, It's `Server Explorer` and it is different from `SQL Server Object Explorer`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with 2.7 Azure SDK.
To get rid of it I went to the C:\users[user] folder and deleted the following files:

- AzureStorageEmulatorDb42.mdf
- AzureStorageEmulatorDb42_log.ldf